# Zero-Inflated Poisson Regression – Warning message: In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced

Tags: r, regression, zero-inflation

I'm trying to model the following data:

[image]

using  zero-inflated poisson regression:

```
model <- zeroinfl(dv ~ c1 + c2 + session | participant, data = dat)
```

where dv is my dependent variable, c1 and c2 are dummy variables for those levels of the independent variable, session is an order-related variable I need to control for, and participant# is a random effect.

However, whenever I try to get the summary for this model, I get the following error message:

> Warning message:
>   In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced

Could anyone provide insight as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Your dataset does not contain variables dv, session or participant. You warning message refers to object but your model was called model.

Comment: The dataset does contain session and participant, but I posted a summary table here. The dv was actually called "stress", but I was rewording it for generalizability... Sorry if this made things harder to interpret!

Comment: I would guess that the problem is due to the specifcation of the inflation equation. If the are some `participant`s that have all zero observations then you will likely see quasi-separation issues. The corresponding coefficient estimates would then be very large etc. But it's hard to say something more without a reproducible example.

Comment: The warning message is because some elements of diag(object\$vcov) are negative. zeroinfl sets vcov equal to the inverse of the Hessian, so somehow your Hessian is not positive definite. I would look at model\$vcov and model$coefficient to see if the problem is what Achim described. Also, I would check that your independent variables are not collinear.

Comment: Thanks for your response Achim! This is definitely a possibility, as there are a few participants that rated the dv as zero throughout the session. Do you have any recommended solutions for me?

Comment: If (quasi-)separation is the problem, the potential solutions are analogous to the corresponding case in binary regressions. So sometimes omitting the separated variables may be appropriate or possibly changing the regressors. But without a concrete example/explanation it is hard to say more.